# Turn off external harddrive bay

Tags: usb, power

I have an IcyBox external hard drive bay with a fan, which is quite noisy.

Seems like you cannot completely turn off the fan, even when the harddrives are all suspended.

However, when I shutdown the RPI the hard drive bay turns off automatically.

Is there a safe way of signalling the bay, that it should turn off completely?

//Edit
Okay Unmounting should work, but then, there is another problem:
As my drives are encrypted I usually just insert the encryption key via ssh and keep the drives mounted.
With this approach I'd need to save the encryption key somewhere before boot, which means that I'd also need to encrypt the RPI flash.

Comment: try unmounting the drive

Comment: unmount drive then turn off usb ports via something like uhubctl (if your model of pi supports)

Comment: Thanks, that should work, although it leaves me with the problem of reentering encryption information